# Vim ignores <cr>

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to setup searching word under cursor with ag/ack, grep etc.
In vimrc adding:

```
map <Leader>b :Bsgrep <C-R>=expand("<cword>") <CR>
```

When pushing \b it makes command line filed with bsgrep + word under cursor, but I also need to push enter because CR is ignored. 
My os is ubuntu trusty with xfce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
map <Leader>b :Bsgrep <C-R>=expand("<cword>") <CR><CR>
```

the first `<cr>` is for your `<c-r>={expression}`

the 2nd `<cr>` is for the command in your command line.

Comment: Maked me smile. So pretty obviosly))

Comment: @user3003873 now you believe that vim will make its users smile.

Comment: Vim makes me smile everyday.