# Vimrc ignoring my <cr>

Tags: vim

I am trying to map the '-' key to move a line down

in my vimrc I have

`noremap - :m .+1 <cr>`

but the carriage return is ignored and displayed in the terminal as `<cr>`

After reading [Vim ignores <cr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379061/vim-ignores-cr) i tried adding an additional `<cr>` but that just echoes the characters twice.

So after pressing the '-' key I have to physically press the `<enter>` key to get the command to run.

I have tried this in mac and linux and get the same results.

Comment: just work fine for me :)

Comment: cannot reproduce here. the two `<CR>` won't help, since it is different problem from yours. have you try starting vim with no plugins no vimrc config. then in command line create the mapping?

Comment: @dimeetel Are you using terminal vim? could you give me an idea of what os, terminal, shell you are using please.

Comment: @Kent I have tried ```vim -u NONE``` then ```:noremap - :m .+<cr>``` and still have the same problem. vim's message bar at the bottom shows ```:m .+<cr>``` and i have to press enter

Comment: `nnoremap - :m+<CR>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if I `set nocp`.
I haven't come across any instructions that this must be set for `<cr>` to work.

So this is the issue.
`set nocp` is set if a vimrc is detected.

if you are testing a custom vimrc and starting vim with `vim -u mycustomvimrc` then despite the fact it is loading a vimrc file it does not `set nocp` and maintains backward compatibility. In such cases you need to `set nocp` explicitly.

Thanks for all the suggestions to get this resolved.

Comment: or use `-N` option when activating vim.

Comment: @yosh :thubmbsup: the switch is a great idea. What I didn't realise was that vims behaviour depended on the name of the vimrc file rather than whether it was present or not.